# How to store value in common file and get the same value in other component in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am working on a project Where I have a dropdown in one component (Header component) and I am assigning a default value to it in an API call on first component load. **Example: value = 1**

Problem is when I change the dropdown **value Example: value = 2** and try to navigate to another component, the header component loads each and every time I navigate to any other component as it is commonly used in structure and the value again changes back to the default assigned **Example: value = 1**

I have tried to achieve this by creating service file and using subscribe in it.
And call it. But each time I navigate to another component the Header component loads and the value again changes.

Is there any way that I can achieve this.

Comment: You are going in correct direction, By using custom service you will achieve this. You need to set the selected value in dropdown and then in next route you should get the value from the service.

Comment: @RohitJindal Thanks for the response I have tried it but as i have mentioned above the header will be called again when I navigate to another component and the value again change to defaultly set.

Comment: You need to put one condition, if there is a value return by service `get` method. then you need to set that value otherwise you have to set a default value. It will work like a champ.

Answer (score 2):

I think your main component could have wrong structure.
If your main component contains `HeaderComponent` and router, it should look something like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<section>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Then navigation in your application via `Router` should not cause re-render of `HeaderComponent`.

If your `HeaderComponent` gets data in `ngOnInit` then it should be instantiated only once:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-header',
   template: 'header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    myData: [];
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getData()
            .subscribe(result => this.myData = result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @User123 either this option, or put some kind of a code snippet to clearer see what do you have.
Also, if you get the dropdown value from API, you probably should just update it through API when it's changed, to persist it.